# Data Structure for Tag Lookups

Tags: database, data-structures, computer-science

I am looking for a data structure to store a large number of "Entries", each of which has some number of "Tags", which will support efficient storage of data and efficient search by tag or collection of tags.

For example, I might be trying to build something like Stack Overflow itself. The "Entries" are questions (with their associated answers), and users can apply tags to the entries. My problem (and likely most uses of user-designed tags) probably follows a sort of Poisson distribution, where a few tags are quite common, but there is a long tail of rare tags. In my actual use case, the "Entries" are reasonably small: often around 1 KB of data, I have on the order of 1 million entries (which may grow in the future), and the number of tags per item is reasonably small (more than 5 would be unusual, but not impossible).

The "obvious" approach is to list the tags by frequency, then create a list of Entry IDs for every single tag. When searching for multiple tags (I support AND for tags, but never OR or NOT) I could start with the rarest tag, then linearly search the Entries of that tag discarding those without the other tag(s). Essentially, I'm building an index for every single tag, along with a list of tags sorted by frequency so I can use the rarest tag first.

My question is whether there is any clever solution that is more efficient -- particularly one requiring less memory for storing all the indexes, but I would also be curious if there is a way to make the "AND" joins more efficient.

[Edits: "OldProgrammer" asked what database I was using. Given the not-excessive size of the raw data (~1GB; may grow) it seems reasonable to keep it in memory, which is why I was asking about data structures.]

Comment: some sample data, database you are using would be helpful.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/